# How to solve toUpperCase issue in Jest testing?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am using Vuejs and Jest. I have following statement in my component:

```
...mapGetters('type', [
      'selectedAddressType',
      'checkDeliveryType',
    ]),
    const keyToDisplayMessage = `${this.checkDeliveryType.toUpperCase()}_${this.selectedAddressType.toUpperCase()}`;
```

and in test file, I have following code:

```
test('If a check is requested', () => {
    const selectedCheckAddress = {
      addressLine1: 'test',
      city: 'test',
      state: 'test',
      zipCode: '12345',
    };
    getters.selectedAddressType.mockReturnValue('Home');
    getters.checkDeliveryType.mockRejectedValue('Regular');
    expect(wrapper.vm.pageTitle).toStrictEqual('Request Submitted');
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

it is giving an error as

```
TypeError: this.checkDeliveryType.toUpperCase is not a function
```

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Why did you make checkDeliveryType a promise? It's expected to be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.toUpperCase()` is a method provided by the [String-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase). It seems your variable `this.checkDeliveryType` isn't a string, hence you can not call this method (as it does not exist on whatever type your variable is at that point in time).

Either fix the type or cast the value manually to a string before and call `.toUpperCase()` on it afterwards. One way would be:

```
const checkDeliveryTypeStr = `${this.checkDeliveryType}`;
const keyToDisplayMessage = `${checkDeliveryTypeStr.toUpperCase()}_${this.selectedAddressType.toUpperCase()}`;
```

But in general it would be a better idea to fix the type correctly in your entire flow.